# has_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

I'm a bit confused as to how to map this migration.

I have two models: user and ticket

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

I believe a ticket should be has_many users because a ticket itself has a creator (which is a user object) and it has an assigned_user (which is also a user object)

```
class CreateTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tickets do |t|
      t.string :status
      t.boolean :complete, :default => false
      t.integer :assigned_user
      t.datetime :deadline
      t.string :description
      t.integer :owner
      t.string :story_type, :default => "Bug"
      t.integer :points, :default => 0
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I put them as integer fields to map the user ID, but I believe that's way off. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The term you're after is "many to many".

Comment: thanks @meagar. I came across that but still am a bit confused. do you know what the migration file would look like? t.has_one :owner, :through => user?

Comment: Your migration shouldn't modify `tickets` or `users`. It needs to introduce a new junction table, probably something like `tickets_users`.

Comment: hmm okay. thanks for the help!